# How can I limit mysqld memory consumption?

Tags: server, mysql

Mysql High Memory Consumption

Recently I have migrated from Debian Server to Ubuntu server and I have noticed that `mysqld` memory consumption on Ubuntu Server is ridiculously high for little to no use...

Solutions?

I was wondering if there are any ways that I can perhaps limit this memory consumption as it does put my server in a dangerously unresponsive position?

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use control groups to accomplish what you're asking.

**Please read before following these instructions:** I read on RedHat's documentation site that libcgroups has been deprecated recently. RedHat provides a guide for creating control groups with systemd [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-Using_Control_Groups#sec-Creating_Cgroups).

Also, in the methods described below *text* denotes a number or file name to be defined by the user.

**Method 1: libcgroups (apparently deprecated)**

You can install libcgroups, which contains a series of utilities for creating cgroups such as cgcreate and cgclassify, by typing `sudo apt install libcgroups`. Once installed, perform the following:

- Create a cgroup called sqlgroup (or whatever you want to call it)

  - Type `cgcreate -g memory,cpu:sqlgroup`
- Set memory limit.

  - `cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=$((*mathExpressionForDesiredLimit*)) sqlgroup`
- Associate new group with the desired process to control.

  - If the process is currently running, use cgclassify by typing `cgclassify -g memory,cpu:sqlgroup $(*PID of mysql process*)`
  - If the process is not running, you can use cgexec by typing `cgexec cpu,memory:sqlgroup *processName* *additional arguments*`

**Method Two: Manual Configuration**

You can also accomplish this manually without installing additional packages using the following (**Note:** You must have systemd 232 or later. `systemctl --version | grep systemd` gives current version info):

- `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/groupname`. This creates a folder under [...]/cgroup/memory, which specifies that the cgroup will control memory. **Note:** change groupname to something that corresponds to the process you want to restrict. You can name it anything. In the previous method I described the groupname was sqlgroup.
- Set the memory limit for the process by creating a file under the groupname folder you created that contains the memory limit in bytes. This can be done using: `echo amount_in_bytes > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/groupname/memory.limit_in_bytes`. Do not alter the name of memory.limit_in_bytes.
- Move the PID of the process you want to restrict into the cgroup.procs file. It can be created with `echo *PID_Number* > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/groupname/cgroup.procs`. **Note:** If multiple processes with different PIDs are to be restricted, you will have to enter each PID into the cpgroup.procs file manually.

More advanced configuration options regarding cgroups can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups).

Comment: Thank you for this helpful post. Although next time I suggest writing for an Ubuntu machine.